# target an element on a popup that isn't yet in the dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, elementor

I'm a bit of a javascript novice. I've just spend 3 hours trawling through stackoverflow trying to brute force an answer to what seems like a simple problem. To be honest i'm not even sure what I should be searching to solve my issue.

I have some javascript I use to bind a google places address autocomplete to an input, this input has been moved to a popup which isn't added to the DOM until a button is clicked, so now the binding fails.

How should I modify the JS to execute once the popup loads?

The new pop-up has a CSS ID of "elementor-popup-modal-97".

```
function bind_autocomplete(){
    // Bind the field based on element ID
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete( document.getElementById(LAA_search_field_id), {types: ['geocode']});

    autocomplete.setFields(['address_component']);
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

function fillInAddress() {
    var componentForm = {
        street_number: LAA_search_field_street_number,
        route: LAA_search_field_street_name,
        locality: LAA_search_field_suburb,
        administrative_area_level_1: LAA_search_field_state,
        postal_code: LAA_search_field_postcode
      };

    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
        var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
        if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i]["short_name"];
            if (addressType=="route" && LAA_strip_street_type == "yes") {
                var lastIndex = val.lastIndexOf(" ");
                val = val.substring(0, lastIndex);
            }
            document.getElementById(componentForm[addressType]).value = val;
        }
    }
}

jQuery(window).load(function(){
    bind_autocomplete();
});
```

I'm not sure if I should be updating `autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete( document.getElementById(LAA_search_field_id), {types: ['geocode']});` to somehow target an ID even if it isn't loaded yet (is that even possible) or should I be wrapping `bind_autocomplete();` in a call that detects if `#elementor-popup-modal-97` has been added to the DOM?

I appreciate any help.

Cheers,

Jamie

Comment: You sure the pop-up is NOT actually part of the DOM? Typically, they will be, just waiting to be made visible. Check page source.

Comment: it is absolutely not part of the DOM at page load - i've checked the source (and I think this JS would work fine if it was)